# How do I execute a function if array items from two arrays are not the same?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have two arrays viz. Transferto and Transfersfrom with elements checking and savings in dropdown list. I like to execute handleSubmit function if the values are not same e.g. Transfer from checking to savings and vice versa otherwise it should flag illegal transaction. In typescript, I am getting error for the angular component.
Can someone please suggest me what is wrong with this code below.

```
   export class BetweenAccountsComponent implements OnInit {
  transfersfrom = [
    {id:1, name: 'Checking'},
    {id:2, name: 'Savings'},
  ];
  transfersto = [
    {id:1, name: 'Checking'},
    {id:2, name: 'Savings'},
  ];
  errorMessage = 'Illegal Transaction !!'
  invalidTransaction = true;
  //Activatedroute
  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }
  handleSubmit() {
   if (this.transfersfrom [name]  === this.transfersto[name])
    this.invalidTransaction = true; 
  } else { 
    this.invalidTransaction  = false;

  }
 
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share error details ?

Comment: I  am getting something like @ name  this 'name' is deprecated.ts(6385)
lib.dom.d.ts(19258, 5): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
Type 'void' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
const name: void

Comment: @ else Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068) And @this in the last line Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: Okay. It seems name is reserved keyword for angular. Can you try `this.transfersfrom ['name']` but i think there is another reason. You can not access the array element via object accessor.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: Failed to compile.

src/app/between-accounts/between-accounts.component.ts:27:27 - error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

27    if (this.transfersfrom['name']   === this.transfersto['name'])
                             ~~~~~~